# What is the most efficient algorithm for factorisation when an approximate value of one factor is known

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, prime-factorization

If I am given the following number:

```
1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350
692006139
```

And am told that one of the factors is in the range:

```
38035634573286525913223768327418691775212180785884 -
37933217936943673922808872755445625858565536638189
```

What would be the most efficient (classical) algorithm for calculating the factors? Obviously, brute forcing would be out of question, and the Quadratic and General Number Field Sieves wouldn't be able to use the range.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing that is likely to happen to you? Do you walk down the street and ask people for numbers to factor?

Comment: @WillJagy I think he did it by head but he is a bit stuck haha. But I am seriously curious of the answer of this kind of problem.

Comment: @Will Jagy, my opinion is that in some practical problems related to cryptography a question like this one is an essential one,

Comment: @z100 , in that case it could use some more context. What sort of things are being discussed in this course, especially for the past week? If this is self study, what is the source of the problem? Most of the time, the answer to a question given in a class is contained in the recent activity of the class.

Comment: @WillJagy This is nothing to do with a university course, or anything educational for that matter. I thought of this problem a while ago when reading 'War and Peace' (my mind does tend to wander often) and haven't found anything yet, leading me to ask this question.

Comment: @Will Jagy, unfortunately I do not know your "past week" information about the "class". All of us know that it is very easy to ask such a question and on the other way hard to resolve.

Comment: @z100 Perhaps I was not clear. i was hoping that the person asking, usually called the OP on this site, would supply some context. I see that I did address the comment to you; however, both you and the OP would be notified of my comment. Indeed, Aleks has left a little bit of context, so that worked about as well as it ever does.

Comment: Aleks, thank you for replying. I do have three books that emphasize factoring methods. So far I do not see anything that says what to do if you are told one factor is in a specified range. The books are Mignotte, Mathematics for Computer Algebra; Bressoud, Factorization and Primality Testing; Riesel, Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization. Maybe I will find something.

Comment: Hmm, this is a very interesting question.. I wonder whether Fermat's method could be useful here

Comment: I suspect there won't be a meaningfully more efficient way to do this known.  Typical composite numbers used as RSA moduli already have prime factors that are close together in size (say, having the same bit length).  The range prescribed here is only 100-300 times narrower than the typical band.  Morally, we shouldn't expect to be able to perform more than 100 times faster than general-purpose factoring methods, and for a 100-digit number those are reasonably fast on current hardware.

Comment: Practically speaking this is asking for a more efficient way to break RSA than the GNFS.  No method is known.  GNFS and not caring about the range is still state of the art.  Obviously n bit RSA uses 2 n/2 bit primes so those are in tight power of 2 ranges.  Granted searching from 2^512 to 2^513-1 isn't happening anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $N$ has a factor $p$ between $0.97213\sqrt N$ and $0.97476\sqrt N$. Then for suitable $a$ (small, but with good factors), $N'=aN$ may have a factor very close to $\sqrt{N'}$, and that can be found by Fermat's method. For example if $a=20\cdot 19$ and $p\approx 0.97476\sqrt N$ then $20p\approx 1.00008\sqrt{aN}$. This $a$ was just a simple ad hoc example and already seems somewhat helpful (for a part of the possible factor range). To me it sounds promising to go look for a nice $a$ with many factor between $0.97213\sqrt a$ and $0.97476\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 2):

Your range has an upper bound about 2-3 percent larger than the lower bound. So, the answer is that there is nothing much you can do simply based on a range like that. This is because you could start with a small range, say 100-102. Then 102-102*1.02, then 102*1.02-102*1.02^2, and so forth. Proceeding like that, you only need about log base 1.02 of $n$ steps to cover the whole range of factors (well, half that to get to the square root). Thus, if you had a good algorithm using ranges of that fineness, you would have a good algorithm in general.

Just multiply the complexity of your special case algorithm by a linear factor, and you have the complexity of a valid general factoring algorithm. Since a linear factor is small beans in the world of integer factorization, an interval that is only fine to the tune of a few percent is therefore essentially useless in simplifying the problem.

Now, your range is very close to the square root, so maybe you are thinking something can be done from that. This still doesn't help, because you could proceed as I mentioned before, but at each step multiply the range or number to factor by an integer so as to transform the problem into one where the range covers any particular value calculated based on the number to factor (like its square root). Then an algorithm that could use a range with a fineness on the order of a couple percent, located anywhere specific with respect to the number to factor, can be used to construct a general purpose algorithm at the cost of a linear factor.

So, the answer to your question is definitely no, a huge range like that is not helpful. You'd just have to forget about the range and use a general purpose algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The question, in its full generality, does not really have an answer, in my opinion. Consider the problem formulated as follows:

> find a computationally efficient algorithm to factorize $N$ knowing that it has a divisor in the range $[a,b] = \{a, a+1, \dots, b-1, b\}$

and call it *"problem $P(N,a,b)$"*. As you are going to see, a good answer can be given only if further information about the size of $b-a$ is given.

If $b-a$ is $O(\log^k N)$, then brute force is polynomially-fast, therefore "very" fast (in the sense of computational complexity) and, if $k$ is small, it is also fast in practice on current hardware.

On the other hand, the very special instance $P(N,1,N)$ is precisely the problem of integer factorization - which shows that in general $P(N,a,b)$ is equivalent to the problem of integer factorization, for which [many algorithms exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms), none of them fast (in the sense of computational complexity).